# JNI CallStaticObjectMethod return NULL in c++

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface

Here is the code in C++ ,where i create a Java VM and i need to call a function from a jar.

```
    JavaVM *jvm;       /* denotes a Java VM */
JNIEnv *env;       /* pointer to native method interface */
JavaVMInitArgs vm_args; /* JDK/JRE 6 VM initialization arguments */
jmethodID constr = NULL;
jmethodID Read_XML = NULL;
JavaVMOption* options = new JavaVMOption[1];
options[0].optionString = "-Djava.class.path=<path_to_my_jar>";
vm_args.version = JNI_VERSION_1_6;
vm_args.nOptions = 1;
vm_args.options = options;
vm_args.ignoreUnrecognized = JNI_TRUE;
/* load and initialize a Java VM, return a JNI interface
 * pointer in env */
long status = JNI_CreateJavaVM(&jvm, (void**)&env, &vm_args);
if (status == JNI_ERR){
    cout << "Fail:  Unable to load JVM \t Exit" << endl;
}
 jclass xml_read = env->FindClass("<MyClass>");
 if (env->ExceptionCheck()){
      cout << "Fail:";
 }
 constr = env->GetMethodID(xml_read, "<init>", "()V");
 if (env->ExceptionCheck()){
     cout << "Fail:";
 }
 Read_XML = env->GetStaticMethodID(xml_read,"readFromXML", "(Ljava/lang/String;)L<MyClass>;");
 if (env->ExceptionCheck()){
     cout << "Fail:";
 }
 const char* filepath = "<My_filepath>";
 const jstring file = env->NewStringUTF(filepath);
 jobject ret_obj = env->CallStaticObjectMethod(xml_read,Read_XML,file);
 if (env->ExceptionCheck()){
     cout << "Fail:";
 }
```

Now the ret_obj is NULL.The Java function i am calling takes a String as argument and returns an Object from another Class different from  MyClass.

Java Method is like this `public static SomeClass readFromXML(String filepath)`

**UPDATE 1**
Inside the CallStaticObjectMethod we have this `jobject CallStaticObjectMethod(jclass clazz, jmethodID methodID,
                             ...) {
        va_list args;
        jobject result;
        va_start(args,methodID);
        result = functions->CallStaticObjectMethodV(this,clazz,methodID,args);
        va_end(args);
        return result;
    }`

After  `va_start(args,methodID);` the value of args is somnething like this `0x002cf5fc "0¦ύ"`
So maybe there is something with the arguments?

Comment: did you check if your MyClass.readFromXML(file) is actually returning null or not?

Comment: Actually i an not sure if i can do this because i just have the jar, so how can i check if it's Java problem or if there is something wrong with the way that i call the CallStaticObjectMethod

Comment: `va_start(args,clazz);` this line is wrong. delete this line and retry. You should never directly parse/dereference a va_list because the implementation can be varied depending upon platform. Generally va_list holds the pointer to stack.

Comment: But if i delete this line the args will not get any value.This is from jni.h file that i have downloaded from JDK files.

Comment: This line that you mention is added by mistake by me when i was writing the post,so this is not the mistake UNFORTUNATELLY

Comment: Notice the syntax hilighting. The following line appears to be hosed: `options[0].optionString = "-Djava.class.path="<path_to_my_jar>";`. You should do somthing about that extra quote mark.

Comment: @igoutas then there it is possible that your jar file is returning null because your calling is fine, you are not getting exception (UnsatisfiedLinkError) either (so the linker can actually resolve the method in jar file). So, considering all this you should first verify that the way you are calling the jar file is actually not returning null. (maybe write a simple java app, include the jar and invoke the SomeClass.readFromXML(file) to see what it returns in java.)

Comment: @Mad Physicist absolutely no problem with this .That was made through the copy from my IDE. Thank you by the way, but i have the exceptionChecks so i am sure that the problem is around  CallStaticObjectMethod

Comment: @ fadedreamz so the value of the args inside the  `CallStaticObjectMethod ` is fine?This souldn't contain somehow me filepath instead of this weird value?

Comment: ok this one solved.It was my bad, in filepath i should define the XML file too and not just the file containing this.Thank you..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok this one solved.It was my bad, in filepath i should define the XML file too and not just the file containing this.Thank you